# Printing a UserControl that uses OnLoaded for rendering

Tags: wpf, xaml, xps, xpsdocument

I'm trying to print a WPF UserControl that I am creating in code. I am doing this with the DocumentPaginator implementation at the end of the post.

The problem I have is that the DocumentPage class is not calling Loaded on my UserControl so the control isn't completely rendering. I can't move the code in OnLoaded to a better location because I am not the maintainer of the control.

What is the right way to fire a Loaded event on the control? I realise the event is only fired when the control is attached to a PresentationSource, but I am trying to send off the print job with out showing the content on screen. I could probably render the control with Visibility=Hidden somewhere, but that feels cheap and hack-y.

```
class MyPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    public MyPaginator()
    {
        PageSize = new Size(800, 600);
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        var uc = new ChartUC();

        uc.Measure(PageSize);
        uc.Arrange(new Rect(PageSize));
        uc.UpdateLayout();

        return new DocumentPage(uc, PageSize, new Rect(PageSize), new Rect(PageSize));
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override int PageCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.Size PageSize
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```